# How to review edits?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I can't see how to review edits. I theoretically have the "privilege" and I recently happened upon a question that had an edit pending, which I approved. But I don't see where a list of pending edits can be accessed. Nor do I see where pending tag wiki edits show up.

Am I missing something?

(I've tagged this [bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) because it needs one of those compulsory tags, but none really seem appropriate...)

Comment: The only _bug_ is that you don't have 10000 rep yet `:-)`

Comment: @Hendrik I'm hoping to patch that bug in the next couple of months

Comment: @Jasper Not if I've hit the rep cap...

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm in the same situation as you were when you asked this question: I'm >5k but <10k. I have approved [exactly one suggested edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4012/doncherry?tab=activity&sort=reviews), but when I go to the suggested edits tab, it's _always_ empty. Could the title of this question be _Can I approve suggested edits with less than 10k reputation?_? If so, I suggest changing it to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list of edits are part of the [moderator-tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (10k privileges). You can approve edits before that but only if you stumble over them. You can see them by looking at the `edit` link below the post. If one or more edits are pending a number is displayed in parentheses behind it, like `edit (1)`. This is by design.

I was asking about the same question, but about tag wiki edits (which didn't had that indicator then) on Meta.SX: [Users with 5k+ rep have “approve tag wiki edits” privilege but can't see list of suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80709/users-with-5k-rep-have-approve-tag-wiki-edits-privilege-but-cant-see-list-of).